# Jquery Drop Down Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I got this kind of Navigation:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Navi 1</a>
<ul class="navisub" style="display:none">
 <li>Subnavi 1</li>
 <li>Subnavi 2</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Navi 2</a>
<ul class="navisub" style="display:none">
 <li>Subnavi 3</li>
 <li>Subnavi 2</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Mainproblem is, when I hover the "Navi 1" li, the subnavi should show. But when i enter the subnavi with my cursor everything is hiding.

thats my code:

```
$('#navi li').mouseenter(
    function () {
        //show its submenu
        $('ul.navisub', this).css('display','block');

    }).mouseleave( 
    function () {
        //hide its submenu
        $('ul.navisub', this).css('display','none');         
    }
);
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you all very much!

Comment: Could you show your CSS as well, or post a http://jsfiddle.net that demonstrates the problem? `mouseenter` is definitely the right event to use here.

Comment: Which element is represented by `#navi`, it doesn't appear to be in your posted code.

Comment: That's the whole code (without any formatting):
http://jsfiddle.net/V2kLv/

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at my answer yet? It should work with the variable height you mention in your comment below.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem some time ago and I solved it using `hover` (also use show/hide):

```
$('#navi li').hover(
    function () {
        //show its submenu
        $('ul.navisub', this).show();
    },
    function () {
        //hide its submenu
        $('ul.navisub', this).hide();         
    }
);
```

Comment: yeah, but when i reduce the height of the #navi li element to , let's say, 50 or 60, the hover doesn't work... the submenu appears but when i want to enter the submenu, it disappears directly. No chance.

When i leave the height at 90px its possible... BUT when i move my mouse just one pixel above the submenu, the other navi-li triggers...

Information:
The submenu is centered.

Comment: You have a problem in your CSS: when you write `ul#navi li` that means the style is applied to any children `li` element of any level. You should use `ul#navi > li`

Comment: Still the same problem. When i change the

ul#navi > li {float:left;height:90px !Important;} into height:60px it doesn't work after I leave the li element.

Comment: I edited your code to this: http://jsfiddle.net/V2kLv/1/ testing it in Chrome works. Let me know if this is enough. (I added a border just to debug the exact position of the li elements)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your target browser requirements it is possible to do this without JavaScript. See a pure CSS [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/EaWXY/).

If you need something the works in IE6 then jQuery is a good solution. I can expand on this with a jQuery version if needed :)

Edit: [jQuery version here](http://jsfiddle.net/EaWXY/1/).

Second Edit: [New version](http://jsfiddle.net/EaWXY/3/) which might do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Given this, I presume you meant for your <ul> to have an id of "navi"?

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Navi 1</a>
    <ul class="navisub" style="display:none">...



$('#navi li').mouseenter(
    function () {...
```

Comment: Yes, right...sorry, forgot to add it in the demo code. In the productive code, it's added.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a bit of animation too. Using the toggleFade

```
$('#navi li').hover(function() {
$(this).find('ul.navisub').stop(true, true).fadeToggle(600); 
});
```

Notice the .stop method, this will stop the animation from queuing, from hovering on/off faster than the animation time. You can change the (600) to whatever you'd like at the moment it's set to 0.6 seconds as its in milliseconds.

Checkout the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V7Pye/)